# MYSQL move frequently updated column in different table for better performance

Tags: mysql, pdo

I have a simple user table in which there is a column named 'activationStatus' which keeps on updating very frequently, is it a better practice to move that column in another table named 'activaton' and use the userId as its foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

***Maybe.*** I wouldn't do it unless it could be proved under load-testing that it makes a difference to your application.

There are tradeoffs for performance. For example:

- How frequently would you have to join that second table to the user table anyway? Joins are not so bad when you join to the primary key, but they're not free.
- What is the ratio of reads to writes? You say the activationStatus is updated very frequently, but are reads still 10x as frequent?

Ultimately, no one on Stack Overflow can answer this for you without saying, "but you should test your own application with your own representative traffic to be sure."

Another strategy is to store the activationStatus in another data store like Redis, so you are always writing to fast memory.